# excel vba code for approximate filter data with list of values

Tags: vba

My current code filter only the exact match from a list of Filter Criteria.
Could you help in changing the code to approximate match filter from the Emp list
I have listed the code below. A quick fix would be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
Sub Filter_My_Data()

Dim Data_sh As Worksheet
Dim Filter_Criteria_Sh As Worksheet
Dim Output_sh As Worksheet


Set Data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set Filter_Criteria_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter_Criteria")
Set Output_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")


Output_sh.UsedRange.Clear


Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False

Dim Emp_list() As String
Dim n As Integer

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Filter_Criteria_Sh.Range("A:A")) - 2

ReDim Emp_list(n) As String

Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To n
    Emp_list(i) = Filter_Criteria_Sh.Range("A" & i + 2)

Next i


Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 12, Emp_list(), xlFilterValues


Data_sh.UsedRange.Copy Output_sh.Range("A1")

Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False


MsgBox ("Data has been Copied")

End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to be clearer about what you are looking for when you say "approximate match".  Are you talking about using woldcards or something else?

Comment: Yes using wild cards.. Eg:  If my Filter Criteria has "London", it should also filter me "London, Manchester", "London, London Eye",  "Road, London" etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can only use wildcards with a maximum of two expressions.

```
AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*foo*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*bar*"
```

You cannot do this with an array of values

```
AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("*foo*", "*bar*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

will only return exact matches.

If you want to do this in code you will need an alternate method.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it was a Range.  Try `"*" & xlFilterValues.Text & "*"`

Comment: No problem Gareth , but it still gives error as, Compile error: Invalid qualifier

Comment: My mistake, the previous code was completely wrong and misleading!  Apologies.

Comment: My requirement has array of values to be filtered.... could you please help with the alternate method... I am in badly need to fix this... apologies for asking more on this Gareth ...your help will be greatly appreciated ..thanks in advance Gareth. I can share the workbook if required..

Comment: Hi.  I'm afraid I wouldn't be able to download your workbook on my work computer.  Essentially you need to read your source row-by-row, compare each row to your list of values (using `Like`) and if there is a match, copy the row to the destination page.  If you know how, it would be faster to use an Array.  Afraid that is all I can do at the moment.

Comment: You mean using the VBA code or with some excel formulas ? Could you please elaborate this approach ?